# How to use wget to download pdf from sci-hub links

Tags: download, wget

I actually post this on stack overflow at first, However, I got immediately close vote. So I tried it here.

---

http://sci-hub.cc/ is a site aim to share academic papers freely around the world.

For example I want to download this paper

http://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.47.331

I can directly type this url in my browser

http://journals.aps.org.sci-hub.cc/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.47.331

**then after a while, there will be a pdf opened in your browser(if you have pdf plugin installed) or popup up a download window for asking download a pdf. In both case, the true pdf link is something like below**

http://tree.sci-hub.cc/772ec2152937ec0969aa3aeff8db0b8f/leggett1975.pdf

**However, as I tested, the true pdf link is random each time and I can't know it in advance until the browser get it**

Now I prefer to download paper using wget. Sure, simply direct download

```
wget http://journals.aps.org.sci-hub.cc/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.47.331
```

will not work. But we could use "Grab" feature which often used to download a website to grab things down below this link http://journals.aps.org.sci-hub.cc/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.47.331. But I tried recursive options like `--mirror`, also fails.

On the other hand, I tried "grab" function in "Internet download manager" which correctly grab the real pdf link, as shown below

[image]

**I thought the grab function in IDM is the same as wget, and maybe wget is even more powerful than IDM. Then why `wget --mirror` can not get the real pdf file? How to correctly use wget in this case?**

Comment: The answer is `wget http://tree.sci-hub.cc/772ec2152937ec0969aa3aeff8db0b8f/leggett1975.pdf`  (and by the way, the link you said redirects, doesn't, though it does open the pdf in its own website. If it did redirect then wget would probably get it from that link.. But anyhow, you can use wget to get the link directly, as shown)

Comment: @barlop Hi, barlop. Thank you for answering. I think you probably misunderstood me. The only link I know is `http://journals.aps.org.sci-hub.cc/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.47.331`. However `http://tree.sci-hub.cc/772ec2152937ec0969aa3aeff8db0b8f/leggett1975.pdf` is a link that I didn't know and probably random each time it generated by the website. I certainly can't wget the pdf link without knowing it.

Comment: `wget http://journals.aps.org.sci-hub.cc/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.47.331 -qO - | grep -m1 -Eo 'http://[^ ]+\.pdf' | wget -qi -`

Comment: @guest Thank you very much! Your approach is clever! But there seems some error in your command, I got some error message when running it, and would you like to make an answer?

Comment: @guest And I don't understand the option `-qO -`, kind of magic to me. Why this will output the content of a html file and which html file it corresponds to?

Comment: I've tested several times and it works for me, what error msg did you get? `-qO -` = `-q -O -` = quiet & output to file "hyphen", which stands for stdout. So the html content is piped to grep to extract pdf link, then piped to wget to be downloaded.

Comment: @guest Thank you for explanation. I understand why I got errors. I am using GnuWin32 wget, somehow, it doesn't support direct pipe, so I have to use | xargs wget. Besides, I have a doubt. Since the pdf link is already in the html source page, why wget -r can not detect this pdf link while other tools like IDM can?

Comment: sorry i'm unfamiliar with `wget -r`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
link=http://journals.aps.org.sci-hub.cc/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.47.331

# extract pdf link with grep
wget $link -qO - | grep -Eom1 'http://[^ ]+\.pdf' | wget -qi -

# use built-in crawling (refer to the manual)
wget -rHA '*.pdf' -e robots=off $link
```